# read_sql_query() throws "'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'" with SQLAlchemy 2.0.0

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

First of all, I'm a totally new guys in the dev world
I'm currently taking courses in AI / Data Science and one of my work is to use a SQL Database to make prediction using Prophet, then use these predition to make a PowerBI
But currently, I'm stuck with the Python code, I'm not a developer initially, so I have no clue where the problem is:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from prophet import Prophet
import pymysql


engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:Password@localhost:3306/data")
query = "SELECT Cle_Produit, Date_Facturation, SUM(Quantite) AS Total_Quantite FROM ventes GROUP BY         Cle_Produit, Date_Facturation"
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)

df = df.pivot(index='Date_Facturation', columns='Cle_Produit', values='Total_Quantite')
df = df.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={'Date_Facturation': 'ds', 'Total_Quantite': 'y'}, inplace=True)


m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
forecast = m.predict(future)

forecast[['ds', 'yhat']].to_csv('forecast.csv', index=False)
```

It returns me this message:

> Importing plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "f:\Backup\Cours\Cours\Explo Data\app3.py", line 9, in 
> df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
> File "F:\Programmes\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py",
> line 397, in    read_sql_query
> return pandas_sql.read_query(
> File "F:\Programmes\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py",
> line 1560, in read_query
> result = self.execute(*args)
> File "F:\Programmes\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py",
> line 1405, in execute
> return self.connectable.execution_options().execute(*args, **kwargs)
> AttributeError: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'

Please, can somebody help me?

I want this python script to create a csv file with the prediction from prophet.
I want Prophet to use the table ventes from the DB data, and it should use the column `Cle_Produit`, `Quantite` and `Date_Facturation`

Answer (score 52):

The latest version of SQLAlchemy (2.0) has removed `Engine.execute`. For the time being you may need to downgrade SQLAlchemy

```
python -m pip install --upgrade 'sqlalchemy<2.0'
```

(or the equivalent conda commands if you use conda).

Or, as [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75309237/message-optionengine-object-has-no-attribute-execute/75309321#comment132893751_75309321), wrap the query with [sqlalchemy.text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text).

```py
from sqlalchemy import text

# ...

with engine.begin() as conn:
    query = text("""SELECT * FROM tbl""")
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

Or see [InnocentBystander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8459557/innocentbystander)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75568252/5320906) for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for you help !
I tried your solution, both, but I still have the same problem.
I forget to say, I work on Visual Studio Code with Anaconda Env, and I tried it also in a jupyter notebook and VSC notebook, nothing worked

Comment: Unfortunately I use neither VSC nor Jupyter.  But probably you have to find the env in VSC and ensure that the packages are installed there (and probably using conda, not pip).

Comment: pandas 1.5.3 does not work for me with SQLA 2.0.0. If I try `df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT 1 AS foo", engine)` I get "AttributeError: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'". If I try `with engine.begin() as conn:` followed by `df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT 1 AS foo", conn)` I get "sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: 'SELECT 1 AS foo'"

Comment: @GordThompson  rats, I thought 1.5.3 had the 2.0 fixes, but the release notes just say they are "working towards" compatibility.  Thanks for checking

Comment: However, `df = pd.read_sql_query(sa.text("SELECT 1 AS foo"), conn)` does work.

Comment: Is there an open git issue for this?

Answer (score 30):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75310173/attributeerror-optionengine-object-has-no-attribute-execute) a similar problem is discussed.

The syntax that works for sqlAlchemy 2.0 and that is consistent with the prior api is.

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text as sql_text
    connection = create_engine(bla)
    query = "blo"
    df = pandas.read_sql_query(con=connection.connect(), 
                                  sql=sql_text(query))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works also fine with `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis`.

Comment: This answer is preferable since it doesn't include downgrading of any packages. Long-term perspective.

Comment: seems you also have to explicitly call .connect() as well

Answer (score 10):

For pandas `read_sql_query`, there are two things that are easy to get wrong.  To avoid this error you need to pass a connection (not the engine) and you need to use the text function to convert the query.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://usr:pwd@localhost/dbs")
conn = engine.connect()

query = text('SELECT * FROM table')
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

Replace "usr", "pwd", "dbs "and "table" with your own strings.
You can also read the whole table with pandas `read_sql_table` without using text. Setup as above:

```
df = pd.read_sql_table('table', conn)
```

Some links into the sqlalchemy documentation for more about engines and text:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines_connections.html

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text

Comment: This helped me as I was not using the text method on the string based sql query

Answer (score 4):

[This issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51015) has now [fixed](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/5477#issuecomment-1495512688) in ***pandas 2.0.0*** with the pull request([Make pandas/io/sql.py work with sqlalchemy 2.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/48576)).

Comment: ... which breaks other things, including py37 support:)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this, the git issue for reference:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51015

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. My sqlalchemy version is 2.0.5.post1. So I have just replaced the engine with engine.connect().

Your code:

Before:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:Password@localhost:3306/data")
query = "SELECT Cle_Produit, Date_Facturation, SUM(Quantite) AS Total_Quantite FROM ventes GROUP BY Cle_Produit, Date_Facturation"
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

After:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:Password@localhost:3306/data")
query = "SELECT Cle_Produit, Date_Facturation, SUM(Quantite) AS Total_Quantite FROM ventes GROUP BY Cle_Produit, Date_Facturation"
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine.connect())
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, switching to session.connection() fixed the issue

```
pd.read_sql(query, db_session.connection())
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution#01:
Open cmd or terminal and Try with

```
pip install --user --upgrade "sqlalchemy<2.0"
```

**Must restart your kernel**