# AttributeError: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy v2.0.0 works in a different way - they have changed some of the api.

Following investigation I found a solution.
My code was simply:

```
s_settings_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine_cloud)
```

The error like the title, "AttributeError: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'"

I will answer my own post below.

I tried using various versions but did not like the idea of getting locked with historic components.

Comment: This question and the answer below was instrumental in solving same issue we encountered.  Thanks.  As noted, context is using the new version.

Answer (score 33):

Adding the text import:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
engine_cloud = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://usr:pwd@localhost/dbs") # replace with your parameters
s_settings_df = pd.DataFrame(engine_cloud.connect().execute(text(query)))
```

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: Just upgraded to sqlalchemy2 and hit this same problem. read_sql_query() no longer worked but this method did

Comment: The 'old' way seems much simpler and more intuitive to me as a rather inexperienced user.

Comment: It's a incompatible change in sqlalchemy2, `create_engine` is broken but `psycopg2.connect('dsn')` works.

Comment: Potentially simpler fix from the duplicate question:

Replace `pd.read_sql_query(query, engine_cloud)` with `with engine_cloud.connect() as conn: pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)`

Comment: I also have this problem,also tried this solution and the jupyter said: name 'engine_cloud' is not defined

Comment: @lior1zh2000 it assumes that you've created it with something like this:`engine_cloud = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://usr:pwd@localhost/dbs")`

Comment: Well done @NAJ for this post and answer. It's really good that you're looking out for the community in this way.

Comment: Recently, ran into this. Thanks for the suggestions.