# Python: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is my Code, I ran it on my vscode:

```
engine_sql = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://abcd:xxxx@tt.t.t.tt/fruit?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+8.0',
    fast_executemany=True)

sql_query = f'''
SELECT TOP(10)
   A.[Fruit_Name]
  ,B.[Store_Location]
FROM ['fruit'].[dbo].['info']  A
LEFT JOIN ['fruit'].[dbo].['shop']  B
ON A.fruit_ID = B.fruit_ID
'''

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, engine_sql)
```

error:

```
'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

I've checked other solutions. When I use text():

```
engine_sql = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://abcd:xxxx@tt.t.t.tt/fruit?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+8.0',
    fast_executemany=True)

sql_query = text(f'''
SELECT TOP(10)
   A.[Fruit_Name]
  ,B.[Store_Location]
FROM ['fruit'].[dbo].['info']  A
LEFT JOIN ['fruit'].[dbo].['shop']  B
ON A.fruit_ID = B.fruit_ID
''')

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, engine_sql)
```

error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 527: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I still cannot figure out how to fix it. This is just part of the code. If I run the whole code, there is no error. That's pretty strange to me.

Comment: The answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75310173/attributeerror-optionengine-object-has-no-attribute-execute does not use the `read_sql_query` shortcut.

Comment: @TimRoberts however I have dtype in read_sql_query, can I set astype with dataframe?

Comment: I don't see a dtype in your `read_sql_query, but you can change the dtype on any column.