# How to retrieve a Hive query as a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, hive, pyodbc

I want to connect to a Hive database via ODBC using `sqlalchemy`. I managed to connect and query using `pyodbc` instead of `sqlalchemy`. Here is what I've done:

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=my_dsn", autocommit=True)
pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM database.table LIMIT 10", cnxn)
```

This works in principle, but I get this warning:

> UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy

Thus, I want to switch to `sqlalchemy`, but the following does not work:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://my_dsn", 
    connect_args={"autocommit": True}
)
pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM database.table LIMIT 10", engine)
```

> AttributeError: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'

Next attempt:

```py
engine.connect()
```

Next error:

> Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: AnalysisException: default.schema_name() unknown for database default. Currently this db has 0 functions.

**How can I connect to my database using `sqlalchemy`?**

Or is there some other easy way to make queries and get the result in form of a DataFrame?

**EDIT:**
I'm using Python 3.9.11, sqlalchemy 2.0.12, and pandas 1.4.2.

Comment: What is your `pandas` and `sqlalchemy` versions?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75309237/read-sql-query-throws-optionengine-object-has-no-attribute-execute-with) might helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, one would use [PyHive](https://pypi.org/project/PyHive/) with SQLAlchemy, but unfortunately the PyHive README says

> Project is currently unsupported

and it has not been updated to work with SQLAlchemy 2.

So, as you've noted, this works

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=my_dsn;UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH")

sql = "SELECT 1 AS id, 'foo' AS txt"

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)
```

but it emits the warning

> UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.

At least for now, we can suppress the warning

```py
import warnings

import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=my_dsn;UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH")

sql = "SELECT 1 AS id, 'foo' AS txt"

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)
```

and wait to see if PyHive eventually gets revived and updated to work with SQLAlchemy 2.